# Primefaces Tree Table single select mode and shift key conflict

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Am using PrimeFaces 3.5 and a Tree Table in single select mode. The single node selection is working fine in the following situation:
1- user clicks on different nodes (there is only one node selected at any time)
2- user clicks on different nodes with Ctrl key down (there is only one node selected at any time)

both 1 and 2 from above are working correctly, except when the user uses the keyboard shift key. Even though the selection mode is single, the user is managing to select multiple nodes using the shift key, this causes an error because my back bean selection method is expecting one TreeNode and not TreeNode[] array.

Any idea how can I disable the shift key on this tree table?

```
 <p:treeTable  value="#{bean.obj.root}" var="somthing" id="myTreeTable"
               selectionMode="single"  selection="#{bean.selectedNode}">
 </p:treeTable>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and fixed it. The problem is in Primefaces 3.5 source code. inside the tree table onRowClick event, the shift key was handled correctly but right underneath there was a wrong if statement that triggered the re selection of the nodes. here is the right code that fix this problem:

The problem:

```
     if(this.isMultipleSelection && shiftKey)
```

The fix

```
     if(this.isMultipleSelection() && shiftKey)
```

It was comparing the existing of a function and not the return value of the function.

```
onRowClick : function(event, node) {
                if($(event.target).is('td,span:not(.ui-c)')) {
                var selected = node.hasClass('ui-state-highlight'),
                    metaKey = event.metaKey||event.ctrlKey,
                    shiftKey = event.shiftKey;

                if(this.isCheckboxSelection()) {
                    this.toggleCheckboxNode(node);
                }
                else {
                    if(selected && metaKey) {
                        this.unselectNode(node);
                    }
                    else {
                        if(this.isSingleSelection()||(this.isMultipleSelection() && !metaKey)) {
                            this.unselectAllNodes();
                        }

                        if(this.isMultipleSelection() && shiftKey) {
                            this.selectNodesInRange(node);
                        }
                        else {
                            this.selectNode(node);
                            this.cursorNode = node;
                        }
                    }
                }
                PrimeFaces.clearSelection();
            }
        };
```

Comment: This bug is fixed in Primefaces 4.0 and later.